# SQL Query Where Columns List Keys With/Without Boolean

Tags: sql, oracle

Imagine I have a table like below:

```
|-----|-------|
| KEY | VALUE |
|-----|-------|
| A   | 0     |
| B   | 1     |
| C   | 0     |
|-----|-------|
```

What I'd like to do is to perform a SQL query that would give me a table like below:

```
|---------------|------------|
| Without Value | With Value |
|---------------|------------|
| A             | B          |
| C             |            |
|---------------|------------|
```

So Column A is where Active = 1 and Column B is where Active = 0. But my SQL is basic and I don't know quite how to achieve this (if it's at all possible). Anyone have any ideas?

This on an Oracle DB.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: This is not an easy query to do in SQL; possible, but this sort of rearrangement is often better done at the application layer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle. Added that to the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Agreed but it's only for some one off documentation. Essentially I want to export this info so I can copy/paste it into a dev Wiki every now & then. It's not worth the hassle to write a report or similar. I could copy/paste it by hand but as a developer, it's 2nd nature to try & automate things a bit :)

Comment: For a one-off report, do each query separately, and put the values into a spreadsheet so they are side-by-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a full outer join between the list of keys with a value and those without:

```
select no_val.key as "Without value", with_val.key as "With Value"
from (
    select key, row_number() over (order by key) as rn
    from kv
    where value = 0
 ) no_val
 full outer join (
    select key, row_number() over (order by key) as rn
    from kv
    where value = 1
 ) with_val 
 on no_val.rn = with_val.rn;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/RMKRRA65292

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without resourting to self-joins by giving each row an index using the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function and then use a `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT Without_Value, With_Value
FROM   ( SELECT t.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS idx
         FROM   table_name t )
PIVOT  ( MAX( Key ) FOR Value IN ( 0 AS Without_Value, 1 AS With_Value ) );
```

**Output**:

```
WITHOUT_VALUE WITH_VALUE
------------- ----------
A             B
C
```

Comment: This one looks very succinct which I like but I found it a little tricker to extend/change than a_horse's answer. Big thanks for pointing me towards `PIVOT` though. Time to read up so I can use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
select case when value=0 then key else null end as "Without Value",case when value=1 then key else null end as "With Value" from key_value
```

Comment: The OP's example shows that keys `A` and `B` are displayed in the same row - this displays them in separate rows.